In Puppeteer 22, what is the appropriate replacement for no-wait xpath queries?
In prior versions of Puppeteer, we could query elements using an XPath like so
  const xpath = `//TD[contains(text(),"sometext")]/following-sibling::td`;
  const elements = await page.$x(xpath);

These functions have been removed, and the guidance is to
  const xpath = `//TD[contains(text(),"sometext")]/following-sibling::td`;
  const elements = await page.waitForSelector(`xpath/${xpath}`);

But this has different behaviour. It waits (which we don't want) and returns 1 element (we used to get arrays).
Is there any way to use XPath queries the way we used to in the Puppeteer v22.10?

page.$ or page.$$ (and family, like $$eval) work fine. See How can I get an element by xpath?. Note that xpath/ prefix is discouraged: "While we maintin prefixed selectors, the recommended way is to use the selector syntax documented above."

Yup, that's it.  I think I had a typo in my first test - if you make that an answer i'd be happy to mark it

Thanks for confirming. Already answered in the dupe.
